# Error importing 'pynput' library in python 2.7 in ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, python, pip

I want to use `pynput` library in python 2.7 to control mouse and keyboard in Ubuntu 16.
I get this error in **python shell**:
  [image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to `import pynput` you need to have it on your `Ubuntu` first.

You can do it using:

```
 pip install pynput
```

More info can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

The error shown in your photo - shows a need to install `xlib` which can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install  python-xlib
```

or:

```
sudo pip install svn+https://svn.code.sf.net/p/python-xlib/code/trunk/
```